# GhostScript: Bug under High Sierra setting PDF Metadata?

Tags: shell, unix, pdf, ghostscript

Can anyone confirm the following behaviour on MacOS 10.13 High Sierra with GhostScript? I don't get the problem when using 10.12 Sierra.

When I create PDFs in GhostScript, it always leaves the Title, Author and other metadata blank.

I know that you can set the metadata with PDFmarks within the PostScript file itself (or a secondary merged PS file that just contains PDFmarks), but that requires manually setting the field for each file.

Currently, my PDFs fail PDF-X validation until I manually add the metadata.

My PostScript does contain DSC comments, and the GS documentation implies that this should be picked up, as `ParseDSCCommentsForDocInfo` is true by default.

```
/usr/local/bin/gs \
    -dPDFX \
    -dNOPAUSE \
    -dBATCH \
    -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
    -sOutputFile="$filename" \
    -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK \
    -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
    "$f" \
    /Library/PostScript/PDFX_def.ps
```

The source of the PostScript does not seem to be a factor: Adobe apps like InDesign, MacOS's cgpdftops, all behave similarly.

Here's a simple test PS file. Distiller takes the comments and uses them for DocInfo; GhostScript doesn't on MacOS 10.13.

```
%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: (MyTitle.file)
%%Creator: (MyApp: cgpdftops CUPS filter)
%%CreationDate: (Saturday, February 03 2018 10:19:01 GMT)
%%For: (User Me)
%%BoundingBox: 36 36 576 756
%%Pages: 1
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
%%BeginSetup
% this is where fonts would be embedded
%%EndSetup
%%Page: (1) 1
%%BeginPageSetup
% this is where page-specific features would be specified
%%EndPageSetup
% Draw a black box around the page
0 setgray
1 setlinewidth
36 36 540 720 rectstroke

% Draw a two inch blue circle in the middle of the page
0 0 1 setrgbcolor
306 396 144 0 360 arc closepath fill

% Draw two half inch yellow circles for eyes
1 1 0 setrgbcolor
252 432 36 0 360 arc closepath fill
360 432 36 0 360 arc closepath fill

% Draw the smile
1 setlinecap
18 setlinewidth
306 396 99 200 340 arc stroke

% Print it!
showpage
%%EOF
```

Comment: Should your title maybe be "**Set** PDF Metadata" instead?

Comment: You're going to need to post an example to look at. Also, you are executing PDFX_def.ps, what happens if you don't do that ?

Comment: If I don't use the def.ps file, I get the same. Honestly, it's any PDF. I'll put up an example.

Comment: @KenS, can you provide a PS file where GhostScript correctly interprets DSC comments, so that I can try it here?

Comment: Every file I've tried which is DSC compliant works perfectly well. Using the example file in ghostpdl/examples/golfer.eps with this command line "gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf /ghostpdl/examples/golfer.eps" produces a PDF file where the Title is "golfer art+". The file you supplied above produces (with the same command line) a PDF file containing a blue and yellow smiley with a title of (MyTitle.file) and an Author of (User Me). Additionally the application is (MyApp: cgpdftops CUPS filter). I suppose the obvious question is what version of Ghostscript you are using?

Comment: 9.22. I have to add -dBATCH to get it to work, but I still get no metadata on the golfer.eps file, except for "Untitled" in the Title.

Comment: Just using "ps2pdf golfer.eps" produces the same results. I've re-installed GS.

Comment: I can get Ghostscript to work correctly on MacOS Sierra, but not on High Sierra. Might some bug in the OS cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of MacOS Mojave 10.14.3 and GhostScript version 9.26, this now fixed. I can only presume it was a bug in GhostScript or MacOS.